# Is this way correct to solve this question in Permutations and Combinations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have this question in Permutations and Combinations,

You have $3$ sections $A, B$ and $C$. You need to answer $12$ questions out of $20$ in section $A$. $4$ out of $6$ from section $B$. In section $C$, answer $5$ out of $8$, but the first $3$ are compulsory, and choose $2$ from the remaining.

I answered it like this, but for section $C$ I'm not really sure if it's correct or not:

$Sec A = n= 20, r=12, C(20,12) = 125970$

$Sec B = n= 6, r=4, C(6,4) = 15$

$Sec C = n= 8, r=5, C(8,3) * C(5,2) = 56 * 10 = 560$

$125970 * 15 * 560 = 1058148000$

Thanks

Comment: Section C - you only need to have $C(5,2)$ as the first part is $C(3,3)$

Comment: I see, alright thank you so much